# Very big persistent container for storing large amount of flags sets

Tags: c++, boost, stl

The problem is following: I have certain amount of words (let's say 20M), each containing some bits used as flags; all stored in single continuous binary file.

What I would like to do is to get access to those words in *container like* style, so `container_instance[i]` allows me to access *i-th* word. To get things more complicated, I cannot store all words in memory at one time, they have to be stored back to file and memory freed for those not used for long period. To simplify things the whole sequence is partitioned to 1K fragments, so we need to free and allocate such 1K blocks. Memory should be freed after some time or after certain number of times container have been accessed.

Thread safety in nice to have. But I can protect externally.

The implementation I have currently only allocates blocks on demand (empty or read from file if they are available; file is not sparse, so everything after the last byte in file is allocated empty) and it is not nicely done. Not frees at all, so unused blocks remain in memory forever.

I started to think about nice looking solution and I would like to know whether any elements from STL or Boosts can help me build such container not by engraving it step by step from scratch?

I am not expecting full solutions, rather pointing "you can use *that* for *that*".

Comment: `boost` is a help: their iterator building stuff (like `fascade`) will help you make random access iterators.

Comment: Use a 64 bit system, and `mmap`. Done. Read=page in, free=page out. You can't beat the OS working together with the CPU.

Comment: I cannot use `mmap()` because I have to access files through wrappers as the code cannot rely on POSIX or any other OS stuff.It's like embedded code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mmap](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) system call to map your file into memory. You can use pointer arithmetic with that buffer, so access by index is not a trouble.

Mapped pages are virutual and managed by the kernel, allowing to save unused memory blocks and load/flush them at transparently to you. Also, using [madvise](http://linux.die.net/man/2/madvise) probably can enable some optimisations.